# Pegar id do botão para fazer update

Tags: php, mysql

Boa tarde, eu estou tentando fazer um update em uma table, dentro desta table tem um botão que guarda o id do banco, e envia esse id pra outra pagina, ou seja esse id precisa ser usado em duas funções, eu preciso pegar esse id do botão e fazer um update nesta mesma pagina, eu coloquei um form entre as `<td>` da tabela e tentei pegar o id dentro do botão pra fazer o update nesta pagina, mas não consigo pegar esse id, porque ele é enviado a outra pagina, e lá funciona perfeito, mas nesta pagina não. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Meu codigo ta assim:

```
//Coloquei o update pra fazer no inicio da pagina
 if((isset($_GET['action'])) AND ($_GET['action']=='gravar')){

 $id = $_POST['id'];

                   $update_query = "UPDATE boletos SET status=1 WHERE id='$id'";
                   mysqli_query($con, $update_query);


}

 <form action='<? echo $PHP_SELF;?>?action=gravar' method="POST"> 
                <tr>                
                  <td><?php echo $row['id']?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['categoria']?></td>
                   <td><a href="visualizar.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Visualizar</a></td>
   //Aqui ele pega o id do banco e abre outra pagina visualizar,
//mas eu precisava usar esse id também nesta mesma pagina pra fazer o update
</form>
```

Comment: Importante você [edit] seu post e explicar detalhadamente o problema, descrevendo o que tentou e onde está a dificuldade atual, de preferência com um [mcve] do código problemátic. Estudar a postagem disponível neste link pode fazer uma diferença muito positiva no seu aproveitamento do site: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assim ao carregar tu consegue trazer o id para enviar via POST como tu queria no teu update, só adicionar e passar no update o id, OBS: Pegar pelo name o value do input meu_id.

input type="hidden" id="pegaid" name="meu_id" value="echo $row['id']>"

Comment: Obrigado @Pedro Ortriz, vc salvou minha vida, tava me matando aqui kkk funcionou perfeitamente, muito Obrigado, Deus lhe abençoe.

Comment: Lets cooooding! <3